# MySQL query to select group of IDs from one table, depending on query on a second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am sure this would be easy to google if I knew the right words to use, but I've tried and not come up with anything: apologies if this is a common question on SO.

I have one table which lists a set of records which can be one of 4 types.

**table_1:**

```
+-------+------------+------+
| id    | value      | type |   
+-------+------------+------+
| 1     |          x | 1    | 
| 2     |          y | 1    |  
| 3     |          z | 2    |  
| 4     |          a | 3    |      
+-------+------------+------+
```

I have another table which references the id of this table and stores data

**table_2**:

```
+-------+------------+------+
| id    | table_1_id |value |   
+-------+------------+------+
| 1     |          4 | A    | 
| 2     |          2 | B    |  
| 3     |          3 | C    |  
| 4     |          2 | D    |      
+-------+------------+------+
```

I want to write a query that effects:

"Find all the records from table 1 which are of type 1, take the id's of those records, and find all the records in table 2 where 'table_1_id' which match one of that set of ids."

In the above very oversimplified table example that would result in the query returning records with ids 2 and 4  in table 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your looking for `IN`:

```
select * 
from table2
where table_1_id in (select id from table1 where type = 1)
```

Or perhaps you could `JOIN` the tables:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
    join table1 t1 on t2.table_1_id = t1.id
where t1.type = 1
```

Joining the tables could result in duplicate records.  Depends on your needs.

Comment: Ah I didn't know you could use IN in conjunction with another query... that would do it I think... I don't understand the JOIN method though, because I'm not familiar with the JOIN... method.

Comment: @Gideon -- this could help: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: @Gideon i would say use join this will be more efficient then subquery solution

Comment: @sgeddes many thanks! For both the suggestion and the reading. I'll mark  you as correct when the required time has elapsed.

Comment: I think that join is better: it puts a condition between fields from the two tables and has better performance.

Comment: subquery seems to be working faster... have no idea why

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.value,t1.type,t2.value FROM table1 t1,table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.table_1_id AND t1.type = 1;
```

Comment: You need to return the results of `t2`, not `t1`.  Also, I'd recommend using the `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: it does return value from table2, just wanted to show why it is written this way to distinguish `value` from table1 and table2